# Long Integer signed Fixed Point to Real convertion SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog, fixed-point

I need to convert a Long number as Fixed point into a Double rappresentation.
The fixed point math is used into the synthesis process and the Real data type only for validation and simulation.

If I make multiple convertion in chain with multiple datatypes to adjust the format then it is not enough or completely wrong .

In my case with a fixed point mantissa of 44 bit I have 3bit integer+sign bit. Q notation like "sfix_44_48"

As example I am doing this to convert a fixed point integer number into a Real value(getting the number 0.5f ):

```
    logic signed [47:0] fp_number = 48'h0800_0000_0000; // it should be 0.5f
    real r_val;
    real rr_val;
    real rrr_val;
    real tmp;

    initial
        begin
        r_val = $itor(fp_number)/(2**44); // doesn't solve the problem.
        rr_val = real'{fp_number}/(2**44); // doesn't solve the problem.

        $cast(tmp,fp_number>>>44); // doesn't solve the problem
        rrr_val = tmp;
        end
```

$itor(...) is limited to 32bit integer part.
As result of above I get zero or NaN, on Modelsim simulation.

No luck during all these convertions.
the SV LRM doesn't seem to have a clear way to do this convertion.

What is the SV workaround to allow simulations to analize data greater than 32bit size easily? please.

C.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use

```
rr_val = real'(fp_number)/(2.0**44);
```

Do not use any of the `$TtoT` functions from Verilog. They have fixed datatype inputs and outputs.

`2**44` gets computed as a 32-bit 2-complement value and overflows, giving you 0. You can use `2.0` or `real'(2)` instead.

Comment: thanks your answer resolve the proble with the long integer numbers.

the sintax and the use of "2.0" to create a pow(...) operator is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @dave_59 I post this piece of code which show the mess with the convertion.

```
    logic signed [47:0] fp_number  = 48'h0800_0000_0000; // it should be 0.5f
    logic signed [31:0] fp_number2 = 32'h0800_0000; // it should be 0.5f
    real r_val;
    real rr_val;
    real rrr_val;
    real rrrr_val;

    initial
        begin
        $display("48bit fp convertion sfix_44_48");
        r_val    = real'{fp_number}/(2**44);   //  doesn't solve the problem (curly braces valid sintax but wrong convertion + wrong convertion on the denominator).
        rr_val   = real'{fp_number}/(2.0**44); //  doesn't solve the problem (curly braces valid sintax but wrong convertion + denominator convertion OK).
        rrr_val  = real'(fp_number)/(2**44);   //  doesn't solve the problem (numerator OK + the power operation is not properly converted to a Real number as result).
        rrrr_val = real'(fp_number)/(2.0**44); //  solve the problem with long integer fixed points convertion (the braces are not curly anymore).
        $display("r_val[%08f]",r_val,", rr_val[%08f]",rr_val,", rrr_val[%08f]",rrr_val,", rrrr_val[%08f]",rrrr_val); // it should be 0.5 on the fourth data

        $display("32bit fp convertion sfix_28_32");
        r_val    = real'{fp_number2}/(2**28);   //  result totally different than previous 48bit operation, doesn't solve the problem (curly braces valid sintax but wrong convertion + wrong convertion on the denominator).
        rr_val   = real'{fp_number2}/(2.0**28); //  doesn't solve the problem (curly braces valid sintax but wrong convertion + denominator convertion OK).
        rrr_val  = real'(fp_number2)/(2**28);   //  with a 32bit range it apparently solve the problem (numerator OK + the power operation is OK with this range).
        rrrr_val = real'(fp_number2)/(2.0**28); //  solve the problem with long integer fixed points convertion (the braces are not curly anymore).
        $display("r_val[%08f]",r_val,", rr_val[%08f]",rr_val,", rrr_val[%08f]",rrr_val,", rrrr_val[%08f]",rrrr_val); // it should be 0.5 on the fourth data
        end
```

the only valid convertion at 48bit is the fourth case.
For 32bit the third case is valid and also the fourth case.

- First: the classic `pow(...)` operation must be done with this syntax `(2.0**BIT)` which will create a Real division and not a integer division using `(2**BIT)` when a scaling fixed point will be applied.

In this case the operation above is managed as float/double(C style) or real(SystemVerilog)
* Second: the `real'()` cast operation MUST be used with NO curly braces.
I didn't have a Linting tool to proper check the syntax so I would expect a Warning due to the validity of the operation with the curly braces.

- Third: the subdle results are ok if the INTEGER denominator is limited at 32bit operations. 
  As results shown below:

```
 SIM START.
# 48bit fp convertion sfix_44_48
# ** Error (suppressible): (vsim-8604) ./blocks/sim/test_tb.sv(141): NaN (not a number) resulted from a division operation.
# ** Error (suppressible): (vsim-8630) Infinity results from division operation.
#    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Process: /test_tb/#INITIAL#138 File: ./blocks/sim/test_tb.sv Line: 143
# r_val[-1.#IND00], rr_val[0.000000], rrr_val[1.#INF00], rrrr_val[0.500000]
# 32bit fp convertion sfix_28_32
 SIM END.
# r_val[0.000000], rr_val[0.000000], rrr_val[0.500000], rrrr_val[0.500000]
```

The solution is to avoid any not protected casting, like a casting with the braces boundary:

```
r_val  = real'{ byteU,byteH,byteL}  / (2.0**44) ; // WRONG
rr_val = real'({byteU,byteH,byteL}) / (2.0**44) ; // CORRECT
```

If the scaling factor occurs then the operation, generally `/`, must be done with the same type of operands (real/real).

Unsafe way is (real/long) which leads into a nightmare.

Comment: `real'{expr}` is not legal syntax, but some tools are allowing it to pass through undetected and ignoring it.